# SecurityUtils internals of Shiro

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs, shiro

This is actually a common question rather than Shiro specific. What I would like to learn is how `org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils#getSubject` is working. I have checked necessary parts of the `SecurityUtils` and `ThreadContext` and I am totally puzzled now. The basic way that I understand `Shiro's` `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` to work is that it returns the subject which is bound to the currently executing thread. Actually I was expecting something analogous to RequestLocal instead of ThreadLocal.

My questions:

1. How `Shiro` ensures a random point of the application has the same thread as the subject creater thread to provide same Subject? (Maybe it is related to Servlet spec. Would be great pointing necessary part) Particularly I am interested in `JAX-RS`.
2. This is the most confusing part of whole subject. How `Shiro` works at `Servlet 3 Container` where multiple requests are bounding to single thread?

Could someone please shed light on these questions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in detail in [this mailing list thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/shiro-user/201211.mbox/%3CCAAtvD4WLA_Gu_1qOFJBLoo7UbYOLmSSA2yRxCH-5Tq-yZut0ZA@mail.gmail.com%3E)